# Upload device file in firefox

Tags: firefox

I would like to do a complete backup of a SSD partition to my cloud storage provider. I do not have enough disk space so I'm considering uploading the /dev/sda3 device file.

Unfortunately, the reported size of /dev/sda3 is 0 bytes, which is not accepted by my storage provider.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox 65.0, and Baidu Pan.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Your question is a bit vague, it might get closed as "not clear". Are you trying to "backup" your disk via the _file_ `/dev/sda3/? Do you know that, while in the *nix world "everything is a file", `/dev/sda3` is not "a file containing your data", but a special _device_ file. You cannot "upload" it anywhere!

Comment: Uploading a raw disk, as it sounds like you are trying to do, is probably doable via the command-line, but _not_ a good backup strategy because (1) the disk should be unmounted before you begin uploading, (2) you'll be uploading unused sectors unnecessarily, (3) will not be compressed, and (4) will always upload all of the data rather than what has changed since the last backup. Tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish and who is your cloud storage provider.